# Launch a batch script with path modification in EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, windows-server-2016, batch

I am quite new to AWS but I think I understood how to deploy an EC2 instance, what I am trying to do is install apache tomcat and all that is needed for this on a windows server 2016 using the user data field in the instance creation. My problem comes, I think, from the fact that i need to declare new pathes for jre, jdk and awscli. Is there a way to do it ?

Here is my scrypt:

```
<script>
powershell "& {$url='https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/AWSCLI64.msi';$clnt=new-object System.Net.WebClient;$clnt.DownloadFile($url,'C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\installer.msi')}"
C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\installer.msi /qn
setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI"
setx JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181"
setx JRE_HOME "C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_181"
echo aws s3 cp s3://andrea-s-buckets999/followingScript2.bat C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads > C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\followingScript.bat
echo aws s3 cp s3://andrea-s-buckets999/apache-tomcat-8.0.53.exe C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads >> C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\followingScript.bat
echo aws s3 cp s3://andrea-s-buckets999/jdk-8u181-windows-x64.exe C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads >> C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\followingScript.bat
echo aws s3 cp s3://andrea-s-buckets999/jre-8u181-windows-x64.exe C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads >> C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\followingScript.bat
echo C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\jdk-8u181-windows-x64.exe /s >> C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\followingScript.bat
echo C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\jre-8u181-windows-x64.exe /s >> C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\followingScript.bat
echo C:\Users\AdministratorDownloads\followingScript2.bat >> C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\followingScript.bat
C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads\followingScript.bat
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to read the path and append the new path and overwrite it

in PowerShell code

```
$OldPath=(Get-ItemProperty -Path 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment' -Name PATH).Path

$NewPath=$OldPath+’;C:\Something\...\....\bin’
```